# Changing legend title in geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the leggend tittle of geom_hex. By default it generates the colour scale with the label:"count". I am able to delete the legend by show legend = NA, but I am not able to change the name to something else. If I try to use the standard ways to change the legend name it does not work..

Any ideas please?

[image: This happens after usage of the code bellow.]

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + geom_hex() + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Your Title"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, but now the colour scale went from continuous to discrete..